# If $A$ is a component in $(X,d_1) \iff$ $A$ is a component in $(X,d_2)$ then is $(X,d_1)$ homeomorphic to $(X,d_2)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Suppose that $A$ is a component in $(X,d_1) \iff$ $A$ is a component in $(X,d_2)$. Is it always the case that $(X,d_1)$ is homeomorphic to $(X,d_2)$? I have been trying to find a counter example, but everything I try seems to fail. So I think the statement is true, but I have not yet been able to prove it. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\bigcup\{0\}$.

Consider two metric on $X$:

$d_{1}=$usual Euclidean distance, which gives subspace topology viewed as a subset of real line. The components of $(X,d_{1})$ are singletons. (Why?)

$d_{2}=$discrete distance, which gives discrete topology, every subset is an open set. The components of $(X,d_{2})$ are also singletons. (Why?)

Now let $f:(X,d_{1})\rightarrow(X,d_{2})$ be any bijection. $f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})=\{0\}$ is not open in $(X,d_{1})$. Oops...

Detail for the first (Why?):

Let $x\in X$. We show the only connected subset $C\subset X$ containing $x$ is $\{x\}$.

Let $x\in C$ where $C$ is connected. Two cases: $x=0$ or $x\neq0$:

$x\neq0$: Check $C-\{x\}$ and $\{x\}$ are two disjoint open sets whose union is $C$.

$x=0$: Let $y=max(C)$, check $C-\{y\}$ and $\{y\}$ are two disjoint open sets whose union is $C$.

Detail for the second (Why?) is omitted since it is quite obvious.